# Implementing Datetime entities (Synonyms) into dialogflow

Tags: datetime, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Currently, I'm implementing reminders in dialogflow using a webhook. I'm having problems recognising a specific word: "A minute" I want Dialogflow to process this as "one minute" so I can get it as a datetime, this works when I type in "remind me in one minute" but "Remind me in a minute" isn't making a datetime for me. I tried making an entity and add synonyms like "A min", "A minute" etc.. for "One minute" but I did not see any date time results, I however got the value "One minute" back from "A min", I'm wondering if there is a way to receive the datetime back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a composite entity where along with system entity for numbers, you can put synonyms like 'a' for representing 'one' or '1'.

You can read about entities in more details [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities).

Comment: The link you provided is broken.

Comment: check now and see Developer Composite section